# Call magnificPopUp within another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

I would like to display a magnific popup within another functions onclick event. This function has a conditional statement and if false, then the pop-up should be displayed.

I have created a jsfiddle which shows what I am trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/Lilu/heM4q/

Html:

```
<button class="add-wishlist"><span>Wishlist</span></button>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).on('click', '.add-wishlist', function(e) {
    var yes = "1";

    if (yes == "2"){
        // Add to wishlist
    }else {
        // Display error in popup
        $.magnificPopup.open({
           type: 'ajax',
                    alignTop: true,
                    mainClass: 'my-mfp-zoom-in',
                    removalDelay: 160,
                    callbacks: {
                        parseAjax: function(mfpResponse) {
                            mfpResponse.data = "<div class='modal-content'>"+"Sorry you cannot do that"+"</div>";
                        },
                        ajaxContentAdded: function() {
                            return this.content;
                        }
                    }
        });

    }

});
```

Any help will greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want the popup to get displayed.

Comment: yes. But only when the statement is false.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I can achieve the pop-up using inline magnific pop-up instead of ajax.

HTML:

```
<button class="add-wishlist"><span>Wishlist</span></button>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).on('click', '.add-wishlist', function(e) {
    var yes = "1";

    if (yes == "2"){
        // Add to wishlist
    }else {
        // Display error in popup
        displayError();

    }

});

function displayError() {
        $.magnificPopup.open({
                items: {
                    src: '<div class="modal-content">'
                            +'<p class="error">'
                            +'<strong>Whoops!</strong></p>'
                            +'<p>You cannot do that.</p></div>',

                    type:'inline',
                },
                closeBtnInside: true
         });
}
```

Please see: http://jsfiddle.net/Lilu/heM4q/4/